# Zeros of bounded analytic function on unit disk -- infinite Blaschke product

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, blaschke-products

Suppose we have $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ analytic and not identically zero. In order to prove $f$ has an infinite Blaschke product representation (where of course the product defines an analytic function on the disk), **I need to show that $f$ necessarily has countably many zeros $a_j$ in $\mathbb{D}$, and that they satisfy** $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (1-|a_j|)<\infty.$$ This condition seems necessary because the Blaschke product formed by the zeros of $f$ converges locally uniformly on the disk if and only if they satisfy the summation condition, which is how one would show the product is analytic.

Assuming this crucial step, I am able to prove that $f$ has a representation $f(z)=B(z)g(z)$ where $B$ is a product as above and $g$ is a never vanishing analytic function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If there are uncountably many zeros, then (since $\mathbb{D}$ is $\sigma$-compact) the zeros have an accumulation point, hence $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: An accumulation point in the open disk, not the boundary?

Comment: Yes, in the disk. We can write $\mathbb{D}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{|z|\leq 1-\frac{1}{n}\}$, and if the set of zeros is uncountable then one of the disks $\{|z|\leq 1-\frac{1}{n}\}$ contains infinitely many of the zeros.

Comment: This is a very good point, and this doesn't even require boundedness of $f$. I believe the summation condition does though

Comment: @carmichael561 : no, $\mathbb{D} = \{ |z| < 1\}$, consider $\sin(1/(z-1))$, a function analytic on a bounded open set $U$ can have a (countably) infinite number of zeros on $U$, in that case it has an essential singularity on the boundary (otherwise it is identically zero) .

Comment: (sorry I thought you said countably many zeros) following the usual argument of isolated zeros and that $\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$ is finite on any compact where $f(z)$ is analytic (and has no zero on the contour $C$), we get that an analytic function always has a finite number of zeros on any compact set, and hence  (considering as carmichael561 said the compacts $\{ |z| \le 1-1/n\}$) that $f(z)$ has at most a countably infinite number of zeros on $\mathbb{D}$ (more generally on any open set where it is analytic)